# Image link not working in css- django project

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using django (py3) for my website.
I am facing problem in image, I.e on running in the chrome browser , I can't see the image.
The image file is stored in

`website>homepage>static>homepage>images>pic.jpg`

And my css file code for image is

```
header{
    background-image:url("./static/homepage/images/pic.jpg");
    [...] other styling
}
```

When I viewed the source code in the browser, clicked on the css link,. I can't see the blue link in my image url.

I'm not getting what the problem is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partial urls in CSS-files are relative to the location of the CSS file. As I assume your style file is somewhere in static, I think you are using a wrong path to your image.

Comment: @Gnietschow I've checked for the path. I think it's alright

Comment: Are you sure? If your css is for example under  `website>homepage>static>homepage>styles>styles.css`, the url should be `url(../images/pic.jpg)`. I'm a bit doubting, because your url starts above the static folder.

Comment: @Gnietschow my css file is in website>homepage>static>homepage>css>home.css

Comment: Then it should be `url(../images/pic.jpg)` as you are moving from the `css` folder up with `..` and then into the image folder to your picture, because you need a path relative to your css file if you are using `url` in an css file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run collectstatic, see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Okay...In website>website> settings.py, run collectstatic is included

Comment: how are you deploying your website?

Comment: I'm just making the app right now, I'm not sure to deploy or launch it.

Comment: If you are using Django 1.11, refer to the above link, it will get you all set up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell django where is your static file like this in sittings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage/static'),  # not sure if this is the location
]
```

then when you want to get the image:

```
{% load static %}
backgrount-image: url("{% static 'homepage/images/pic.png'%}")
```